# Need to generate a range of date time between dates but time start and end at 02:00:00 am

Tags: pandas, datetime, datetimepicker, date-range

Hello I am trying to generate a date time range between the two dates with an increment of 15 minutes, however I want it to start at 02:00:00 am of the start date and end at 02:00:00 am of the end date. The start and end dates should coming from date picker on my dashboard in the future.

I know I can generate the date time range using the below command however I have not been able to start and end at 02:00:00 am.

```
dates = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/2/2018', freq='15min')
```

I also found on one of the stack overflow articles to force the date range to start at and end at 02:00:00 am, however I am not able to figure out how to pass the dates as they would be in dates format from the date picker but below they are just numbers

```
dts = [dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') for dt in
      datetime_range(datetime(2018, 6, 3,2), datetime(2018, 6, 10,2),
      timedelta(minutes=15))]
```

I am hoping if some one can please help to resolve this issue.

P.S. I am trying to figure out if it is possible before I make changes to the frontend and use date picker instead.

Thanks a lot in advance !!

Comment: `pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018 02:00:00', end='1/2/2018 02:00:00', freq='15min')
`?

Comment: @Wen-Ben, Thanks a lot for the response. This might not be able to fix it. The date picker would return only dates if I am not wrong. how would I pass the dates keeping the time bit in the above code fixed.

Comment: use `pd.to_datetime(start_date + ' 02:00:00')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC

```
d1='1/1/2018'
d2='1/2/2018'
pd.date_range(start=d1+ ' 02:00:00', end=d2+' 02:00:00', freq='15min')
```